# How many samples of a random variable X should I obtain to reliably predict the value of a dependant random variable Y?

Tags: regression, linear-model

I am trying to launch a timing attack against `strcmp` function from the C standard library.

I wrote a program that takes a string as an `input` and compares it with its internal `secret` string. My aim here is to obtain some information about the `secret` string by running the program with different `input` values and measuring its execution time. I know that the program compares strings byte-by-byte, so the number of instructions executed by the program as well as its execution time must depend on the number of longest common prefix of `input` and `secret` strings.

For example:

- `strcmp("for", "foo")` will do 3 comparison operations
- `strcmp("far", "foo")` will do 2 comparison operations

To find the value of the first character of `secret` I am going to generate strings $s_0, s_1 ... s_{n-1}$ having different possible values of the first character. Then I will run the program with input being $s_i$ for all $i \in \{0, 1 ... n-1\}$ and measure the execution time $t(s_i)$. The $s_i$ having greatest $t(s_i)$ will have its first character being equal to the first character of `secret`. Then, knowing the value of the first character I will repeat the same procedure to find out the second one and so on.

The problem is that my measurements of execution time are very inaccurate and strongly affected by other random processes (e.g. program startup time, system load). To cope with that inaccuracy I will execute the program $m$ times with the same input $s_i$ to obtain execution times $t_j(s_i)$ for $j \in \{0,1 ... m-1\}$. Then I will compute $t(s_i)$ average of $t_0(s_i), t_1(s_i) ... t_{m-1}(s_i)$, and proceed as usually finding the greatest $t(s_i)$ and so on.

My questions are:

1. How do I estimate the number of measurements $m$ that would reliably let me distinguish the correct $s_i$ from others? "Reliably" here means "with probability higher than some given $p$".
2. Is it always possible to reach any wanted value of success probability $p$ by simply increasing the number of measurements $m$? How do I find out if it is possible in my case?
3. Are there any techniques except "average the results of many measurements" that could solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that the the [Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) answers first two of my questions.